# Translate Code to Class

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I have this in my MDI parent:

```
Form1 newForm1 = new Form1(); //newForm1 is the instance of Form1
private void MDIParent1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    newForm1 = null; //newForm1 is set to null
}

private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (newForm1== null)
    { 
        // if Form1 is not yet open it will be open 
        newForm1 = new Form1();
        newForm1.MdiParent = this;
        newForm1.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(newForm1_FormClosed); //add event handler when the form close
        newForm1.Show();
    }
    else
        //if Form1 is already open it will just be activate
        newForm1.Activate();
}

void newForm1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    newForm1 = null; //when the Form1 Closed the newForm1 will be set to null
}
```

How I will translate this to a class? It would be something like this:

```
public static void openForm(Form newForm, FormInstance Instance) //newForm is the name of the Form, Instance is the instance of that form
{
    if (Instance == null)
    {
        Instance = new newForm();
        Instance.MdiParent = this;
        Instance.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Instance_FormClosed);
        Instance.Show();
    }
    else
        Instance.Activate();
}   

void Instance_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Instance = null;
}
```

So that I will have this:

```
Form1 newForm1 = new Form1(); //newForm1 is the instance of Form1
Form2 newForm2 = new Form2(); //newForm2 is the instance of Form2
private void MDIParent1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    newForm1 = null; //newForm1 will set to null
    newForm2 = null; //newForm2 will set to null
}

private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openForm(Form1, newForm1); //Form1 is the name of the Form, newForm1 is the instance of Form1
}

private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openForm(Form2, newForm2); //Form2 is the name of the Form, newForm2 is the instance of Form2
}
```

Comment: It may help others if you tell us what `Form1` and `Form2` are. I can only assume that they are `System.Windows.Forms.Form` but you dont say.

Comment: I really still dont understand. You want a class to open the form? something like `FormUtils.OpenForm(Instance)` (I just made that up) Or are you just looking for another way to open the form.

Comment: Yes a class that will open a form if it is not open and activate it if is already open

Comment: I see, and I think I can do you one better....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this time, how about an extension method? I'm assuming that `Form1` and `Form2` are both instances of `System.Windows.Forms.Form`

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void OpenForm<T>(this T frm, Form parent) where T : Form, new()
    {
        if (frm != null && FormOpen(frm.Text))
            frm.Activate();
        else
        {
            frm = new T();
            frm.MdiParent = parent;
            frm.FormClosed += (sender, args) => {frm.Dispose(); frm = null;};
            frm.Show();
        }
    }

    private static bool FormOpen(string name)
    {
        FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

        foreach (Form frm in fc)
        {
            if (frm.Text == name)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

throw this into a new class called `Extensions.cs`

and call it (ex: on `Form1`) `newform1.OpenForm(this)`

If you have problems, let me know and I can get in front of a compiler to figure this out.

Comment: Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint 
Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint

Comment: Take into account recent edits if you try this code. I had to make a change.

Comment: Thats one of the things I had to fix.

Comment: Delegate 'System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler' does not take 0 arguments. Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer.

Comment: Ok, let me throw this into visual studio quick. Give me a min

Comment: Thank you it works. But if the Form is already open, it opens the form again.

Comment: Im not really sure what Mdi is or how to use it. You will probably need to modify the `FormOpen` method to figure out if it really is open. If I were you I would change `if (frm != null && FormOpen(frm.Text))` to `if (frm != null)` first and see it that helps.

Comment: Same thing happens. MDI is just a container of the opening forms

Comment: Sorry. I dont think there is much more I can help you with here... This code should be working, but I think you will just need to mess with it until it works like it should, but at least you have the structure

Comment: No need to Sorry. I modified your work and it's now working. Thank You for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use generics? I dont totally understand what you want to do

```
public static void openForm<T>(T Instance)
{
    if (Instance == null)
    {
        Instance = new T();
        Instance.MdiParent = this;
        Instance.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Instance_FormClosed);
        Instance.Show();
    }
    else
        Instance.Activate();
}

//This was inside the openForm method (which made no sense to me) so I moved it out.
void Instance_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
   Instance = null;
}
```

then you would call it

```
openForm<Form1>(newForm1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want open another forms from main class/form and you want open only one instance of the form then try next approach:

in another forms create a static members:

```
Class AnotherForm1
{
    private static AnotherForm1 Instance;

    //creating a static function for creating/getting Instance
    public static AnotherForm1 CreateInstance()
    {
        if (AnotherForm1.Instance == null) 
        { 
             AnotherForm1.Instance = new AnotherForm1(); 
        }
        return AnotherForm1.Instance;
    }

    //Constructor was made private because we want 
    //that our form instance willbe creating only through CreateInstance function
    private AnotherForm1()
    {
        this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Instance_FormClosed);
    }

    //Here we set reference to Instance to null when form are closed
    private void AnotherForm1_FormClosed(object snder, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        AnotherForm1.Instance.Dispose();
        AnotherForm1.Instance = null;
    }
}
```

Then in main form:

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AnotherForm1 form1 = AnotherForm1.CreateInstance();
    form1.MDIParent = this;
    form1.Show(); 
}
```

So in `CreateInstance` we check:

if instance of our form was created already -> then return reference to it,

if not -> then create new and return reference to it